# Splitting columns more efficiently

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column `x` containg strings composed of numbers a letters like this

```
x
1 a
2 b
3 a
34 c
35 d
```

I want to split this column into two `y` and `z`, one with the numeric value and another with the string so I do

```
df['y']=df['x'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str.get(0)          
df['z']=df['x'].str.split(' ').str.get(1)
```

It's there a more efficient way to do it? When applying this operation in huge files it takes several minutes.

Update: The string and the number are optional and not always appear. There could be one number or one string 
Example:

```
x =['6.1 a', ' d', '6.5', '5.6 c', '6.9', '6.1', '5.9 b', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3', '5.7', '5.7', '4.7 x', '5.1', '5.1']
```

into

```
y=['6.1', '', '6.5', '5.6', '6.9', '6.1', '5.9', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3', '5.7', '5.7', '4.7', '5.1', '5.1']
z=['a', 'd', '', 'c', '', '', 'b', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', '']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply with lambda with is faster than your solution:

```
df["y"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
df["z"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[1] if len(x.split())>1 else "ND")
df
     x    y   z
0   1 a    1   a
1   2 b    2   b
2   3 a    3   a
3  34 c   34   c
4  35 d   35   d
5   1.5  1.5  ND
```

I can't compare with the expand version as I don't have the latest pandas version.
It's faster than the extract version I think.

If you don't care about using pandas methods, using string methods and list comprehension is even faster:

```
y, z = zip(*[(i.split()[0], i.split()[1] if " " in i else "") for i in x])
```

You can easily put this in a df though.

### Timing

With

```
def ori(df):
    df['y']=df['x'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str.get(0)          
    df['z']=df['x'].str.split(' ').str.get(1)


def lam(df):
    df["y"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
    df["z"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[1] if len(x.split())>1 else "ND")
```

Edit: with condition relative timing are the same.

With len(df) = 5

```
%timeit lam(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 818 µs per loop

%timeit ori(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop
```

With len(df) = 10000

```
%timeit lam(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

%timeit ori(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the string character it's not always present. The instruction df["z"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[1]) fails in those cases

Comment: what do you mean ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: ['6.1 a',  '6.3', '6.5', '5.6 c', '6.9', '6.1', '5.9 b', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3', '5.7',
 '5.7', '4.7 x', '5.1', '5.1']

Comment: @user2082695 Is that what you want ?

Comment: Sorry, but your solution is bad, because incorrect parse second value `' d'` of list `x` as number.

Answer (score 1):

I think native apply is the best, but not. I found faster approach:

```
df[['y', 'z']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(' ') for x in df['x'].tolist()])
df['z'] = df['z'].fillna('')
```

My test:

```
import pandas as pd

#testing list
x =['6.1 a', ' d', '6.5', '5.6 c', '6.9', '6.1', '5.9 b', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3', '5.7', '5.7', '4.7 x', '5.1', '5.1']
#10000 lists
x = x*10000
#Dataframe from list x
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
print df.head()
       x
0  6.1 a
1      d
2    6.5
3  5.6 c
4    6.9
```

```
def OR(df):
    #original
    df['y']=df['x'].str.strip().str.split(' ').str.get(0)          
    df['z']=df['x'].str.split(' ').str.get(1)


def AL(df):
    #incorrect parse second value as number instead string
    df["y"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
    df["z"] = df.x.apply(lambda x:x.split()[1] if len(x.split())>1 else "")

def EX(df):
    #extract by reg exprresions - number and string
    df['y'] = df['x'].str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)')  
    df['z'] = df['x'].str.extract('([A-z]+)')
    #remove NaN from columns y, z
    df['y'] = df['y'].fillna('')
    df['z'] = df['z'].fillna('')

def DF(df):
    #create new columns by converting column x to list and spliting 
    #correct parse second value, because before string is space (I think)
    df[['y', 'z']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(' ') for x in df['x'].tolist()])
    #remove NaN - convert it to ''
    df['z'] = df['z'].fillna('')
```

```
OR(df)
print df.head()
       x    y    z
0  6.1 a  6.1    a
1      d    d    d
2    6.5  6.5  NaN
3  5.6 c  5.6    c
4    6.9  6.9  NaN

AL(df)
print df.head()
       x    y  z
0  6.1 a  6.1  a
1      d    d   
2    6.5  6.5   
3  5.6 c  5.6  c
4    6.9  6.9   

EX(df)
print df.head()
       x    y  z
0  6.1 a  6.1  a
1      d       d
2    6.5  6.5   
3  5.6 c  5.6  c
4    6.9  6.9   
DF(df)
print df.head()
       x    y  z
0  6.1 a  6.1  a
1      d       d
2    6.5  6.5   
3  5.6 c  5.6  c
4    6.9  6.9
```

Timing:

```
In [118]: %timeit DF(df)
     ...: %timeit AL(df)
     ...: %timeit OR(df)
     ...: %timeit EX(df)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 95.4 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 338 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 459 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your ext function does not work, it should `str.extract('(\d*)')` otherwise you can the first digit only

Comment: I tried with the regular expression (\d+\.?\d*) to extract the full number with decimals. This solution is slightly slower than my original solution using real data